# UILabel - minimumScaleFactor for multiline

Tags: ios, uilabel

I have multiline UILabel `numberOfLines = 0` with `minimumScaleFactor = 0.75`. But for multiline UILabel with big height and small width, for long words `minimumScaleFactor` don't work....It only takes the last letters of the word and put to a new line (even if letter is only one), but does not compress it. How I make compress text for `minimumScaleFactor` if I have word longer than row?
[see exsample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoOEb.png)

Answer (score 1):

I think **Line Break** is the issue here, Look this images

[image]

if you change the Line break to Truncate Tail then it will work, check this image

[image]

Comment: this don't work, try set width = 50 and height = 500 and you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7bQQ.png)